# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Finally :). thank goodness.

Comment: Don't want to open up a new question for this one: will these moderators complement those that have the office by reputation, or replace? More specific, would we have to nominate e.g. Suresh if we wanted to keep him?

Comment: you can only nominate yourself (no one else). And yes, I have to nominate myself if I want to continue (I did). It's at the primary stage where you can "throw the bums out" :). Note that eventually, there will be people with score above 10k who will have many moderator powers (if not all)

Comment: please please nominate yourself if you're at all interested. we need a diverse group, especially in different timezones.

Comment: I do not understand how each phase works.  Is the [description on meta.math.stackexchange.com](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/community-moderator-election-format-and-design) in effect?